# Derivative of the following integral

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

> Find the derivative of the following function 
>   $$y(x) = \int_{\sqrt{2\pi x}}^{\sqrt{5\pi x}} \sin (t^2) \mathrm{d}t$$

**My work** 
Is this the right answer?
〖sin5πx(√5π/x^2)〗〖+sin〖2πx(√2π/x^2〗)〗

Comment: i can not read this

Comment: See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Be sure to disambiguate between $\sqrt 5\pi x$, $\sqrt{5\pi}x$ and $\sqrt{5\pi x}$, and the likes of it.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: $\dfrac{\sqrt{5 \pi } \sin (5 \pi  x)-\sqrt{2 \pi } \sin (2 \pi  x)}{2 \sqrt{x}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a,b$ are differentiable functions and if $g$ is continuous then, by the [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus),
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} g(t) dt\right)=
g(b(x))b'(x)-g(a(x))a'(x).
$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, I think I should be able to. Thank you.

Comment: Is this the right answer? $d/dy =〖sin((25π^2)/x^3 )〗-〖+sin⁡〖((4π^2)/x^3 〗)〗$

Comment: @L Hunt No, just apply the formula I gave you.  Where does $x^3$ come from? Please edit the question and write your computations.

Comment: It's going to take a really long time to right my computations. Does this look better:$〖sin5πx(√5π/x^2 )〗-〖+sin⁡〖2πx(√2π/x^2 〗)〗$

Comment: @L Hunt It is almost correct. Note that the derivative of $\sqrt{x}$ is $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$. See Raffaele's comment right above.

Comment: $〖sin5πx(√5π/(2√x))〗-〖-sin⁡〖2πx(√2π/(2√x)〗)〗$

Comment: I feel like I'm fumbling around in the dark. I think I need to take a couple of hours to recap and look at the question with new eyes tomorrow. (Have been working on this assignment for a couple of days now)

Comment: I didn't mean to make that a $-sin$

Comment: @L Hunt  Ok, without the minus sign the result is correct.

Comment: Yes!!! Thank you!